# How to show AlertDialog with time after 10 button clicks

Tags: android, timer, counter, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

So I have this simple app that I am making where you try to click a button 10 times in the fastest time possible. I want to show an AlertDialog after you clicked 10 times and have that dialog display your time and have 2 buttons allowing the user to play again which will reset the game or go back to the main menu of the app. I can't seem to figure out how to code the AlertDialog or if I am even putting it in the right place. Please help if you can.

XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/thirty_tap_game_background">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="138dp"
    android:background="@drawable/test_play_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:text="@string/timerVal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:text="@string/countVal" 
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
package com.example.thirtytapgametest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AnalogClock;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int mCount = 0;

private ImageButton startbutton;

private TextView timerValue;

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
    startbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) { 
            if (mCount ==0) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            }

            mCount++;
            countTextView.setText("Taps: " + mCount);
            if(mCount == 10) {
                view.setEnabled(false);
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);


                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setTitle("Game Over!");
                alert.setMessage("Your Score is:");
                alert.setPositiveButton("PlayAgain", null);
                alert.setNegativeButton("Levels Menu", null);

                AlertDialog alt= alert.create();
            }
        }           
    });

}


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        updatedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("Time: " + "" + mins + ":"
                +String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                +String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

    };


}
```

Comment: Do you get any error here?

Comment: What is happening now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problem are you having? Your `AlertDialog` is fine where it is but you probably want to set an `onClickListener` for your `AlertDialog` buttons.  Here is an example of setting the `onClickListener` for the positive button:

```
    // Build an alert dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_message))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_close_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // Close the dialog
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
              });

    // Create the alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // Show the alert dialog
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: This does help thank you, but eclipse is showing an error in my code. In the first line "AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)" it is showing an error with "new AlertDialog.Builder(this)" .  The error message says The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @user3689022 Replace "this" with MainActivity.this replace MainActivity with the name of your activity

Comment: I figured that out. Thank you though!

Comment: Hate to ask more but any idea how you would get the .setPositiveButton to reset my timer and button click count? Or would the best thing to do here to be reset the activity all together?

Answer (score 0):

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            YOUR_CLASS.this).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("HELLO ANDROID");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        // Write your code here to invoke YES event
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Write your code here to invoke NO event
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
```